# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command, which must be closed first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have this error and i dont know how to solve it. I searched how to solve in the internet and every time it was caused by some sql comand (which i didnt understand and its not my case).

Here is the code :

```
public ActionResult ConfirmarCandidatura(int id)
    {
        Candidatura candidatura = db.Candidaturas.Find(id);
        db.Propostas.SingleOrDefault(x => x.PropostaId == candidatura.PropostaId).CandidaturaAceite = candidatura;
        db.Propostas.SingleOrDefault(x => x.PropostaId == candidatura.PropostaId).CandidaturaId = candidatura.CandidaturaId;
        db.Candidaturas.Find(id).CandidaturaAceite = true;
        var candidaturas = db.Candidaturas.Where(x => x.PropostaId == candidatura.PropostaId);
        foreach(Candidatura c in candidaturas)
        {
            db.Candidaturas.SingleOrDefault(u => u.CandidaturaId == c.CandidaturaId).CandidaturaRejeitada = true;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("CandidaturasRecebidas","Candidaturas");
    }
```

Comment: Assuming that `CandidaturaId` is a unique key for `Candiaturas` you don't need the `SingleOrDefault` call inside the `foreach`.  Just do `c.CandidaturaRejeitada = true;`  Otherwise you're doing another call to the DB to get an entity you already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write the following:

```
var candidaturas = db.Candidaturas.Where(x => x.PropostaId == candidatura.PropostaId);
```

you don't really close the `DataReader`. Therefore when you open another `DataReader`

```
db.Candidaturas.SingleOrDefault(u => 
    u.CandidaturaId == c.CandidaturaId).CandidaturaRejeitada = true;
```

you get an error. You should finish the first statement with `.ToList()` or `ToArray()` or something similar. That will give you the actual result instead of `IEnumerable`

As a separate comment, it's a very bad idea to write `db.Propostas.SingleOrDefault(x => x.PropostaId == candidatura.PropostaId).CandidaturaAceite` (you have several like this). If `null` result is **not** possible, use `Single()` instead of `SingleOrDefault()`. If it *is* possible, check for `null` before getting child field - otherwise you will get NullException